# Evaluating Limits of a function

Tags: limits

Hi Guys was attempting this question and was wondering if I was doing the question correctly?

Determine whether or not the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent:-

$$f_n:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_n(x) = 2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

Checking point wise convergence first

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

Taking the Limit as n $\to \infty$ gives the following

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^ne^2$$

$$\implies e^2  \lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x^n$$

substituting $n \to \infty$ gives

$$e^22^{-\infty}x^\infty = 0$$

Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) = 0 = f(x)$$

I was wondering is this limit evaluated correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is not correct. $2^{-n} \to 0$ and $x^{n} \to \infty$ if $x>1$ and we cannot find the limit of the product by applying limit to each factor separately.

When $x=2$ we get $f_n(x)=e^{-2}$ for all $n$ so the limit is $e^{-2}$. For $x<2$ we have $0 \leq \frac x 2<1$ so  $(\frac x 2)^{n} \to 0$. The fact that the limit function  is not continuous implies that the convergence is not uniform.